# What is the easiest way of setting (workflows, programmatically, etc) the value of columns from Business Data Catalogue for new docuemnts?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, document-library, business-data-catalog

In Sharepoint 2007 I am trying to automatically set values read from business data for new documents added to the document list. Right now, when new file is uploaded, user:

1. needs to go to the "Edit Properties" menu item
2. copy the part of the file name
3. paste it into column which is linked from Business Data Catalogue
4. check the name (if the corresponding item was linked correctly)
5. push the ok button to accept the changes.

Is there a way to somehow automatically process new documents (most preferably using workflows attached to document library) so those data would be auto-filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can create an EventReceiver, that will be triggered by ItemAdded and perform required interactions with BDC, no additional actions from user is required. 
Links:

- http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/creating-adding-an-event-handler/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/02/28/sharepoint-2007-moss-wss-creating-an-itemupdating-event-handler-as-a-feature-and-packaging-it-in-wsp.aspx